# $_POST not finding a "name" value

Tags: php, html, post

I am trying to submit a form, it SHOULD send forth a name, but I know I'm messing something silly up and I just can't see it (3 hours of sleep last night + new coding project at work != a smart idea)

Here's my form on one page:

```
<form action="add.php" method="POST">
    <button type="submit" name="exportcult">Export All</button>
</form>
```

And here's the code on the other page, meant to process the POST:

```
if (!isset($_POST["name"]) || $_POST["name"] == '') {
    header('Location: '.$criteria."?error=data");
    die();
}
```

I am getting the error message this sends back, so I know it isn't registering a name - why could that be?

Comment: Don't you mean `if (!isset($_POST["exportcult"]) || $_POST["exportcult"] == '') {`

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confused how the form data actually gets submitted. "name" is the attribute, not the key value that is found in the POST data. You need to specify the name for that element, which will be the key value present in the POST data. You have specified `name="exportcult"` so in the POST data, the variable will be at `$_POST['exportcult']`. However, this value will always be an empty string since you have not indicated a `value` attribute for your button.

Keep in mind that when dealing with submit buttons, *only* the value of the button which was used to submit the form will be included along with the rest of the form data. Try using this:

```
<button type="submit" name="exportcult" value="export">Export All</button>
```

If that specific button was used to submit the form, then `$_POST['exportcult']` should be equal to `'export'`.

For those of you who are unsure: **[buttons *do* get submitted with the form](http://dev.animuson.net/animuson/submit_button_lement.php), but they still have to have a value attribute.**

Answer (score 0):

Your form doesn't contain any field except the button, so `$_POST` will only contain a field `exportcult`.

Edit: Since you use `<button>` instead of `<input>` it might not go into the POSTed data.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
if (!isset($_POST["exportcult"]) || $_POST["exportcult"] == '') {
    header('Location: '.$criteria."?error=data");
    die();
}
```

You're currently checking for a field named "name", when the field is named "exportcult". Additionally, it should be `<input`, not `<button`.

Answer (score 0):

you should add

```
<input type="button" name="exportcult" value="Whatever you want" />
```

and check for `exportcult` on the `isset()` instead of `name`

Answer (score 0):

use exactly this:

```
<form action="add.php" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="name" value="Export All"></form>

if (!$_POST["name"])) {
    header('Location: '.$criteria."?error=data");
    exit();
}
```